# Select object from listbox and show related object to another listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have 2 classes: Doctor and Pacient. They both have a field named codeM. Because a Doctor have a code, many pacients can be assigned to that doctor, when writing a doctor's code in codeM field when creating Pacient objects. (I mean after creating Doctor objects to have their codeM already chosen)

`private int codeM` field definition in both Doctor and Pacient classes.

and 2 forms. In Form1 I have a list of Doctor objects, and in Form2 I have a list of Pacient objects which I transfered to Form1 after I created it. With the following reason:

In Form1 I have a listBox in which I show the List of Doctor objects. The list is the following:  `List<Doctor> listDoctors = new List<Doctor>();`
The list of Pacient objects I passed to Form1 from Form2 is named `listPacients`.

I have a secondary listBox. I want that when I select a Doctor object from listBox1, to compare that doctor's attribute codeM with every patient in listPacients and where is a match to show me in listBox2 those pacients with codeM the same as doctor's codeM.

I don't even know where to start this thing, but I have this code for listBox1, that with the Doctors

```
private void listBox1_doctors_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Doctor currentItem = listBox1_doctors.SelectedItem as Doctor;

               foreach(Pacient p in listaPacienti2)
        {
            if(currentItem.CodM==p.CodM)
            {
                listBox2_pacienti.DataSource = new ObservableCollection<Pacient>(p);
                listBox2_pacienti.DisplayMember = nameof(Doctor.NumeM);
                listBox2_pacienti.ValueMember = nameof(Doctor.CodM);
                listBox2_pacienti.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
            //from this point on i'm stuck. Please tell me how to continue, and how to set dataSource to only show me the desired pacients


        }
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, once you have the selected Doctor, you need to populate the Patients ListBox by calling patientListBox.DataSource = listPatients.  How you get the list of patients for the doctor isn't something we can help you with without more information.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to hard, I commented my code so you can understand it.

```
private Form2 patientsForm; // You somehow have to get the object of this window, for
                            //   example when showing the window with 
                            //   patientsForm = new Form2().Show();

private void listBox1_doctors_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Doctor currentItem = listBox1_doctors.SelectedItem as Doctor;

    int docCode = currentItem.codeM;

    // Basically use Linq to select the first Patient in a list of Patients that matches
    //  the codeM of the doctor.
    Patient patient = patientsForm.listPatients.First(p => p.codeM == docCode);
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to get *multiple* patients with the matching code, just use `.Where()` instead of `.First()`.

```
Patient[] patients = patientsForm.listPatients.Where(p => p.codeM == docCode).ToArray();
```

Comment: I wrote those 3 lines and it gets me nothing in listbox2..and if i try to put these line i already had within for, it also shows nothing .

Comment: This code itself "shows" nothing. It just retrieves Patients from a list. Displaying is up to you. Or do you get an exception when running?

Comment: It tells me "InvalidArgument: The value of "0" is not valid for Selectedindex. Parameter Name=SelectedIndex" 0 is one of the codes I assigned to a doctor and 2 patients. This is when i add the 4 lines with dataSource and so on that I mentioned in for in the example code, and it doesn't show pe the name of the doctors, but their code...

Answer (score 0):

The code [Ian H](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44787998/3862763) provided only handles the retrieving part, if you want to display the patient's name on the `ListBox` then you could do it like this:

```
public class Patient
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    //Other properties

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

}
```

using this will display the patient name to the `ListBox`.

Comment: Glad to help, if this is the answer you are looking for kindly mark this as the answer thanks!